# Downloading Enterprise Apps creates an 'empty app'

Tags: ios, enterprise, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, in-house-distribution

I am attempting to download an app that has been enterprise signed. The app downloads correctly, however there is another app icon that is also 'downloaded'. It is the default icon for apps that do not have icons.

This worked perfectly in iOS7, however now this 'empty app' appears.

Also, the console prints this out:

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad installd[60] : entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'app_1'

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.IhiktR/foo_extracted/Payload/app_1.app/
app_1: 0xe8008016

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.IhiktR/foo_extracted/Payload/app_1.app

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 install_application: Could not preflight application install

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad itunesstored[89] : 0x3c1000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad itunesstored[89] : ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil

Dec  3 08:54:18 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed

Dec  3 08:54:21 Will-iPad SpringBoard[33] : Killing  for app installation

Dec  3 08:54:21 Will-iPad itunesstored[89] : LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.

Dec  3 08:54:21 Will-iPad itunesstored[89] : LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder (null)

Dec  3 08:54:21 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-2715824119902522246/2469171773387578025" requested by itunesstored

Dec  3 08:54:22 Will-iPad mdmd[787] : (Note ) MDM: mdmd stopping.

Dec  3 08:54:22 Will-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd) : (com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 6 seconds

Dec  3 08:54:23 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.myCompany.app_1

Dec  3 08:54:23 Will-iPad installd[60] : profile not valid: 0xe8008012

Dec  3 08:54:23 Will-iPad installd[60] : 0x343000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!
The app was being correctly signed, etc. However the issue was being caused at the bundle ID was not included in the manifest file.